# How show hamburger in drawer when we go to other graph (navigation components with multi module)

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, multi-module

I make application with multi module:
- app 
- SMS

Now I've graph in module app:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/sms_navigation" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.example.messages.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_sms"
        android:name="com.example.messages.ui.sms.SmsFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_sms"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sms">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_sms_not_met"
            app:destination="@id/sms_navigation"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_preferences"
        ... />

    <fragment ... />
</navigation>
```

and in module SMS

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/sms_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_sms_welcome_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_sms_welcome_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.sms.ui.welcome.WelcomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/welcome"
        tools:layout="@layout/list_sms_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/openListSms"
            app:destination="@+id/nav_sms_list_fragment"
            />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_sms_list_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.sms.ui.listsms.ListSmsFragment"
        android:label="@string/list_sms"
        tools:layout="@layout/list_sms_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

When I run application I see home fragment and hamburger of drawer. Next I open drawer and click "sms" row. Show me welcome fragment if variable "enableSMS" is false otherwise open "sms list fragment".

Problem 1:
When I there (sms list fragment) I see button Up. I want see hamburger instead of button Up. When open settings or home fragment it's ok. How can I solve it?

Problem 2
The case may be related to the first problem
When I have open sms list fragment and press back button I'll back to fragment welcome a for while and show me again sms list fragment. 
I can't back to home fragment because I have loop. In fragment (sms and welcome) I have code:

```
// SmsFragment
if (enableSMS) findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_sms_not_met)

// WelcomeFragment
if (enableSMS) findNavController().navigate(com.example.sms.R.id.openListSms)
```

If I start from home fragment and go to sms list fragment next I press back button I would like see home fragment because it was first fragment before opened sms fragment.

Any idea?

Thanks for help :)